# how do i see what the http referer is sending on android

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have previously asked similar questions and had no solutions.
My question relates to the http referer that is sent from an android device when using chrome for android.
My application required playback of video with the http referer required. On all desktop browsers I can see what the http referer is being sent as and set permissisons based on these. Different browsers send different headers, like Chrome for desktop sends the page URl , where IE sends the video players js URL from Flash player./
I do not know how to see what an android device is sending and it is not working for me, please can someone tell me how to know what my page is sending as the referer on android chrome. Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the logs on the target server, and if you're not seeing anything, then obviously it's not sending any referrer to it. For confirmation, you could use Fiddler 2, use your computer wifi as a proxy for the web connection, and inspect the packets that go through that way.

Comment: Thank you , these are good ideas. I will have to investigate. If as I suspect, no referer is sent, why would that be, could it be something blocking it on my end or is it just that chrome on android always sends null referer

Comment: You should try some of the different browsers on Android. You should specifically test if there is a difference between your mobile data connection and your wifi connection. You should try clearing the cache of your browser. And you should tell your web browser to request the desktop version of the web site in case the web site is redirecting you to a different location because it thinks your requesti is coming from a mobile browser. Also, you should ensure that the spelling, the protocol, and the subdomain are the exact same ones your Android Chrome browser is using.

Comment: Thanks again. Been round this block a few times, tried other browsers, Opera on android behaves like Chrome does which is expected, Firefox is ok it plays the media ( meaning referer is sent) - maybe there is an extra string in the URL referrer that chrome android sends and I need to work it out. Maybe the best bet is the server logs, I will ask my admin

Comment: I looked into the logs on Amazon S3 where the media is located. Strangely, the http referer is sent from android when requesting an xml file in the same location - but the referer is not sent when requesting an mp4 video or m3u8 playlist video, the filed is simply "-" or null.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... referer is not being sent and my WAF rule is blocking the content. I'm using jwplayer to pull the video, not sure if that has anything to do with it.